# get hahes key to string in perl

Tags: string, perl, hash, hashmap

I do not understand why $test is '1' and not 'foo'. Is there any way to write 'foo' (written in %hash) to $test?

```
#/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

my %hash;
$hash{'test'} = {'foo' => 1};

print keys %{$hash{'test'}}; #foo
print "\n";
print values %{$hash{'test'}}; #1
print "\n";
print %{$hash{'test'}}; #foo1
print "\n";

# here is the part I do not understand
my $test = keys %{$hash{'test'}};
print "$test\n"; #1 but why? I was expecting #foo
```

How can I push 'foo' in $test?

Comment: It's a good idea to use modules like `Data::Printer` for debugging purposes, so you can see how data is structured.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`keys()` returns a list. But your assignment to a scalar (`my $test = keys ...`) puts it into scalar context. Therefore it is evaluated to the length of the list, which is `1` in your case.

Comment: This isn't really true. Keys returns a list in list context and a scalar in scalar context.  There wasn't a list to evaluate. Consider `perl -le '$n = ( 1, 2, 7); print $n'`. There's no list there: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array?

Comment: The answer to the last part of the question is to make the assignment in list context.  `my ($test) = keys ...`

Answer (score 3):

```
my $test = keys %{$hash{'test'}};
```

When assigning a list like `keys` returns to a scalar, what's assigned is the length of the list. Which is 1 in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is the solution of my problem. my @test = keys %{$hash{'test'}}; print "$test[0]\n";

Comment: Actually, it is not true that all lists are turned into counts in scalar context. In this case, the function `keys` has a special functionality in scalar context, which is to return the number of keys. If it had truly been a list, the first item would have been assigned to `$test` and the rest of the list would have been discarded (and warnings would be issued).

Answer (score 2):

When the return value from a Perl function confuses you, it's always worth checking the documentation for that function - paying particular attention to the section talking about how the return value varies in different contexts.

The very start of [perldoc -f keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys) says this (emphasis mine):

> **keys HASH**
> **keys ARRAY**
>
> Called in list context, returns a list consisting of all the keys of the named hash, or in Perl 5.12 or later only, the indices of an array. Perl releases prior to 5.12 will produce a syntax error if you try to use an array argument. *In scalar context, returns the number of keys or indices.*

You're assigning the results of the expression to a scalar variable. The expression is, therefore, evaluated in scalar context and you get the number of keys in the hash (i.e. 1).

To fix that, force the expression to be evaluated in list context by putting parentheses around the variable:

```
my ($test) = keys %{$hash{'test'}};
```